# leaflet searchbox returns no result

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I cannot get the sample data from a leaflet searchbox to work.
I get no errors, but the 'timer' in the searchbox keeps spinning, and no results are returned.

The output-map on the website with the sample data, *is* working for me:
https://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-search
However, when I run the code local, in Rstudio-viewer of in firefox, the searchbox is *not* working.

Running the latest leaflet and leaflet.extras

Can someone verify/reproduce my issue, or is it just me?

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
# Markers ----
cities <- read.csv(textConnection("
City,Lat,Long,Pop
Boston,42.3601,-71.0589,645966
Hartford,41.7627,-72.6743,125017
New York City,40.7127,-74.0059,8406000
Philadelphia,39.9500,-75.1667,1553000
Pittsburgh,40.4397,-79.9764,305841
Providence,41.8236,-71.4222,177994
"))

leaflet(cities) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, weight = 1, fillOpacity=0.5,
             radius = ~sqrt(Pop)/50 , popup = ~City, label=~City, group ='cities') %>%
  addResetMapButton() %>%
  addSearchFeatures(
    targetGroups = 'cities',
    options = searchFeaturesOptions(
      zoom=12, openPopup = TRUE, firstTipSubmit = TRUE,
      autoCollapse = TRUE, hideMarkerOnCollapse = TRUE )) %>%
  addControl("<P><B>Hint!</B> Search for ...<br/><ul><li>New York</li><li>Boston</li><li>Hartford</li><li>Philadelphia</li><li>Pittsburgh</li><li>Providence</li></ul></P>",
             position='bottomright')
```

sessionInfo:

> R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build
>   18362)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252
>   [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] leaflet.extras_1.0.0 leaflet_2.0.3.9000
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_1.0.3
>   leaflet.providers_1.9.0 packrat_0.5.0           digest_0.6.23
>   later_1.0.0              [6] mime_0.8                R6_2.4.1
>   jsonlite_1.6            xtable_1.8-4            magrittr_1.5
>   [11] rlang_0.4.2             promises_1.1.0          tools_3.6.2
>   htmlwidgets_1.5.1       crosstalk_1.0.0         [16] shiny_1.4.0
>   yaml_2.2.0              httpuv_1.5.2            fastmap_1.0.1
>   compiler_3.6.2          [21] htmltools_0.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer..
it seems to be a knowsn issue...

https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras/issues/143#issuecomment-450461384

described solution below worked for me:

> I figured out how to make the search work with the CircleMarkers
>   (removing the path check), you have to go into your R library path : 
>   R Library path#\leaflet.extras\htmlwidgets\build\lfx-search\
>
> Open lfx-search-prod.js and search for "e instanceof t.Path ||" , and
>   then delete it and save the file. Your CircleMarker search should work
>   now